# batch removing lnk from desktop

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, lnk

Im using a batchfile stored on a usbdevice to clean up computers. Im looking for a solution to remove ink files from desktop. Now i print it manualy in my batch. EKS:

```
del /s /q /f "%userprofile%\desktop\Send til OneNote 2013.lnk"
del /s /q /f "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Send til OneNote 2013.lnk"
```

I want a solution like: 
I have a folder stored at my usbdevice caled lnk
Then i copy all lnk files i want to remove to this folder
And the million question Batch: remove lnk from desktop if they are stored at usbdevice/lnk

Answer (score 0):

Found it my self

```
for %%G in ("f:\lnkremove\*") do IF EXIST "%userprofile%\Desktop\%%~nxG" ECHO del "%userprofile%\Desktop\%%~nxG"
```